# How to get the total time passed flutter - Working with timer flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-timer

I have a Timer that has a small animation which is a circle around it. The Timer is called from another route to start (`ExamTimer(size: 40.0),`). And when ever I navigate to another route I get the following Error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
ExamTimerState#c1b45(tickers: tracking 1 ticker) was disposed with an active Ticker.

ExamTimerState created a Ticker via its TickerProviderStateMixin, but at the time dispose() was called on the mixin, that Ticker was still active. All Tickers must be disposed before calling super.dispose().

Tickers used by AnimationControllers should be disposed by calling dispose() on the AnimationController itself. Otherwise, the ticker will leak.

The offending ticker was: _WidgetTicker(created by ExamTimerState#c1b45(lifecycle state: created, tickers: tracking 0 tickers))
The stack trace when the _WidgetTicker was actually created was:
#0      new Ticker.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:66:40)
#1      new Ticker (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:68:6)
#2      new _WidgetTicker (package:flutter/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:237:80)
#3      TickerProviderStateMixin.createTicker (package:flutter/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:168:34)
#4      new AnimationController (package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:245:21)
#5      ExamTimerState.initState (package:azmoonasli/models/ExamTimer.dart:27:18)
#6      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:58)
#7      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#9      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5551:32)
#10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#12     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#13     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#14     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#15     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#16     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#17     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#19     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#20     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#21     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#22     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#23     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
#26     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#27     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#28     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
#29     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#30     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#31     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
#32     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#34     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
#35     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#36     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#37     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#38     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#39     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#40     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#41     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#42     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5551:32)
#43     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#44     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#45     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
#46     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#47     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#48     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
#49     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#50     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5551:32)
#51     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#52     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#53     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
#54     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#55     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#56     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
#57     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#58     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#59     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#60     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#61     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#62     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#63     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#64     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#65     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#66     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#67     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#68     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#69     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#70     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#71     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#72     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#73     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#74     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#75     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#76     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#77     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#78     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#79     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#80     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#81     ParentDataElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4617:11)
#82     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#83     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5551:32)
#84     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#85     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#86     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#87     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#88     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#89     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#90     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#91     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#92     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#93     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#94     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#95     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#96     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#97     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#98     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#99     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#100    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#101    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#102    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#103    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#104    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#105    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#106    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
#108    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#109    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#110    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#111    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#112    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#113    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#114    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#115    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
#116    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#117    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#118    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#119    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#120    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#121    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#122    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#123    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#124    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#125    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#126    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#127    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#128    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#129    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#130    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#131    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#132    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#133    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#134    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#135    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#136    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#137    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#138    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#139    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#140    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#141    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#142    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#143    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#144    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#145    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#146    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#147    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#148    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#149    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#150    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#151    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#152    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#153    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#154    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#155    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#156    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#157    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#158    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#159    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#160    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#161    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#162    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#163    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#164    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#165    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#166    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#167    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#168    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#169    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#170    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#171    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
#172    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#173    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#174    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
#175    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#176    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#177    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#178    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#179    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#180    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#181    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#182    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#183    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#184    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
#185    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#186    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#187    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#188    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#189    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#190    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#191    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#192    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#193    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#194    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
#195    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#196    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#197    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#198    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#199    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#200    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#201    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#202    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#203    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
#204    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#205    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#206    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#207    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#208    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#209    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#210    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#211    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#212    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#213    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#217    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#224    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#225    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#226    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#227    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#228    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#229    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#230    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#231    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#232    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#233    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#234    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#235    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#236    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#237    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#238    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#239    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#240    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#241    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#242    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5219:32)
#243    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5561:17)
#244    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
#245    _TheatreElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:605:16)
#246    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
#247    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#249    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4413:5)
#250    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
#251    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#252    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#253    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4557:5)
#254    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:94:11)
#255    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
#256    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5452:14)
#257    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
#258    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#259    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#260    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4413:5)
#261    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
#262    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5452:14)
#263    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
#264    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5452:14)
#265    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
#266    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#267    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#268    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4298:5)
#269    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
#270    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#272    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2432:33)
#273    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:773:20)
#274    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:283:5)
#275    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1102:15)
#276    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1041:9)
#277    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:957:5)
#281    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:259:10)
#282    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:217:3)
(elided 3 frames from package dart:async)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      TickerProviderStateMixin.dispose.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:185:13)
#1      TickerProviderStateMixin.dispose (package:flutter/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:203:6)
#2      StatefulElement.unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4435:12)
#3      _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1748:13)
#4      _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1746:7)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Here's my code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'dart:math' as math;

    class ExamTimer extends StatefulWidget {
      final double size;
      ExamTimer({@required this.size, });



      @override
      ExamTimerState createState() => ExamTimerState();
    }

    class ExamTimerState extends State<ExamTimer> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
      AnimationController controller;


      String get timerString {
        Duration duration = controller.duration * controller.value;
        return '${duration.inMinutes}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
      }

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        controller = AnimationController(
          vsync: this,
          duration: Duration(minutes: 20),
        );
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);

        controller.reverse(from: controller.value == 0.0 ? 1.0 : controller.value);

        return Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[ AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: controller,
                builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                  return CustomPaint(
                    size: Size(widget.size, widget.size),
                      painter: TimerPainter(
                    animation: controller,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    color: themeData.indicatorColor,
                  ));
                },
              ),



            AnimatedBuilder(
                      animation: controller,
                      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                        return Text(
                          timerString,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                        );
                      }),
          ],
        );
      }
    }

    class TimerPainter extends CustomPainter {
      TimerPainter({
        this.animation,
        this.backgroundColor,
        this.color,
      }) : super(repaint: animation);

      final Animation<double> animation;
      final Color backgroundColor, color;

      @override
      void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
        Paint paint = Paint()
          ..color = backgroundColor
          ..strokeWidth = 5.0
          ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

        canvas.drawCircle(size.center(Offset.zero), size.width / 2.0, paint);
        paint.color = color;
        double progress = (1.0 - animation.value) * 2 * math.pi;
        canvas.drawArc(Offset.zero & size, math.pi * 1.5, progress, false, paint);
      }

      @override
      bool shouldRepaint(TimerPainter old) {
        return animation.value != old.animation.value ||
            color != old.color ||
            backgroundColor != old.backgroundColor;
      }
    }
```

So I have 3 questions:

1. How to `dispose()` the timer when user manually Navigates to another route?
2. I need to know The time from when user started `ExamTimer()` to when he navigated to another route(Total time passed).
3. How to Navigate automatically to another route when the timer finishes it's duration.

A sample code or any approach would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You need to dispose your `AnimationController` by this way

```
controller?.dispose();
```

About your questions:
1. This is how you can dispose a `Timer`

```
    yourTimer.cancel();
```

2.Eleapsed time can be calculated ether by using `StopWatch` or `Timer`

- StopWatch

  ```
  //start a stopwatch
  final watch = StopWatch()..start();
  //Eleapsed time
  watch.eleapsed //returns a Duration
  //Stop it
  watch.stop()
  //You can also reset when you return to your page
  watch.reset();
  ```
- Timer

  ```
      //Start 
      final timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds:1), (Timer ticker){
      if(ticker.tick == 2){//Wait for  1*2 seconds
      //Navigate here
      }
      //Total eleapsed time 
      timer.tick*yourDurationUnit // used when creating this timer
      )
  ```

  3. Navigate automatically

  Timer timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), (){
    //Navigate here
   });

**NOTE:** You  should dispose `Timer` and `StopWatch` in `dispose` method or it'll cause memory leaks

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. but there's 2 things I'm still stuck with.

1- Since its in another dart file, How to access it to call the `controller?.dispose();`.

2- I'm calling the `ExamTimer()` in another route. How can I dispose it from that route?

actually in both of them I'm trying to understand how to call a method on a dart file from another dart file.

Comment: You shoud dispose at the same route (ExamTimerState). override the `dispose` method in `ExamTimerState`

Comment: forgive me for my low level questions but how to do it when I'm in another route?

Comment: You don't need to do it from another route, Each page has its own dispose will be automatically disposed once you're leaving. However you can save a key of your page then pass it to another page where you can call `key.currentState.dispose();` (not recommanded)

Comment: well actually I'm in `route1()` and am calling the `ExamTimer()` as a widget. and when the user leaves, they will go to `route2()`. Meanwhile I want to dispose the timer which is in `ExamTimer()` that I never actually been there I was just calling it as a widget.

Comment: `dispose` is also avalaible in widgets. It comes from `StatefulWidget`(ExamTimer). Just override it in `ExamTimer`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212542/discussion-between-user8773560-and-taba).

Comment: Hello. Can we please continue our discussion now? I'll set a bounty if you want.

Comment: Tell me about the issue

Comment: about question 1 which you said use `controller?.dispose();`. would you please mention where to call the dispose?

Comment: and about question 2. I'm using a `Timer` not a stopwatch to call the `elapsed` method. is there any equivalent for it in `Timer` class or I should consider using a stopwatch?

Comment: Question 1. Dispose and cancel are placed in dispose method available in StatefulWidget by overriding.... Question 2: you can use tick in Timer to get total of ticks ( how many time the Duration passed as param is elapsed)